# ionic 2 - Application error DEVICE_READY_TIMEOUT

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic2

My Ionic 2 running on Opensuse Linux. The app runs and builds fine, However I am not able to change `DEVICE_READY_TIMEOUT` as it is set to 2000ms

I tried changing the value of `DEVICE_READY_TIMEOUT` in `main.js`, but that file is regenerated every time I run ionic build or run. Could anyone help ?

At the moment it throws an Application Error, on debugging in browser it says

> main.js:25553 Native: device ready did not fire within 2000ms. This
>   can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing
>   plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them. (anonymous) @
>   main.js:25553 main.js:25548 DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 19860 ms

I have tried reinstalling a number of times, its the same. I am able to work with the app through chrome debugging. But on the android phone it shows an Application Error Dialog box.

The issue surfaced only after adding the angularfire2 library for firebase database.

```
System Info
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.1
Node Version: v6.9.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Finally found out, the issue started when I was forced to remove the plugins and reinstall them due to the bugs in the current ionic 2 Rc3 framework. I ended up not reinstalling the device plugin as it wasn't saved in the package.json file nor in the config.xml.

so the solution was to simply add the device plugin

```
ionic add cordova-device-plugin --save
```

Don't forget to add the --save option, as this adds it to your config file, and is useful should you need to reinstall the platform & plugins over again.

The other part of the problem - TIMEOUT_ERRORS can be solved by adding a line to the config.xml , if your device is taking longer to load up during the startup.

```
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="400000"/>
```

The timeout value is in milliseconds. as my app was taking around 30 seconds to load, I have set the timeout value to 40 secs.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/